# can pthread_mutexattr_setrobust apply to pthread_rwlock_t?

Tags: linux, pthreads, posix

the [robustness](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutexattr_setrobust.3.html) of mutex is very important to my program since it can handle the case when a process died without releasing the mutex.

But according to the document, `pthread_mutexattr_setrobust` only apply to `pthread_mutex_t`, instead of `pthread_rwlock_t`, is there any approach to set the robustness of `pthread_rwlock_t`? Or its implementation is robust by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> according to the document, `pthread_mutexattr_setrobust` only apply to `pthread_mutex_t`

More precisely, `pthread_mutexattr_setrobust()` sets a property of a `pthread_mutexattr_t` object, and these are used (only) for configuring objects of type `pthread_mutex_t`.  This happens at initialization of the mutex via `pthread_mutex_init()`.

The corresponding initialization function for read/write locks is [`pthread_rwlock_init()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_rwlock_init), and its documentation shows that the corresponding attribute object type, accepted by that function, is `pthread_rwlockattr_t`.  Implementations may provide whatever properties they like as extensions, but the only one [specified for this type](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/pthread.h.html) by the current version of POSIX is [`pshared`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_rwlockattr_setpshared.html).  Thus no, there is no (portable) robustness option for pthreads read/write locks.